# Copying a Stream using offsets

Tags: c#

I am using the UWP APIs to use the audio capture features of Windows, so I can record audio from a microphone input.

My code looks like this:

```
            var capture = new MediaCapture();
            var inStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio,
                MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Communications,
                AudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Raw,
                AudioDeviceId = @"\\?\SWD#MMDEVAPI#{0.0.1.00000000}.{51965008-3820-4de1-98a0-a54a6d8e53f6}#{2eef81be-33fa-4800-9670-1cd474972c3f}"
            };

            MediaDevice.DefaultAudioCaptureDeviceChanged += MediaDevice_DefaultAudioCaptureDeviceChanged;

            await ThreadHelper.ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                capture.InitializeAsync(settings).AsTask().Wait();
            });


            capture.AudioDeviceController.VolumePercent = 100;
            MediaEncodingProfile profile = new MediaEncodingProfile();
            AudioEncodingProperties audioProperties = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(48000, 2, 16);
            profile.Audio = audioProperties;
            profile.Video = null;
            profile.Container = new ContainerEncodingProperties() { Subtype = MediaEncodingSubtypes.Wave };


            await capture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(profile, inStream);
```

This code above works, and I am able to capture microphone input into the `inStream` stream.

How can I write the contents of `inStream` to another stream? Take the next couple of lines as an example.

```
            var transmitStream = vnc.GetTransmitStream();

            await inStream.CopyToAsync(transmitStream); //This doesn't compile.
```

`transmitStream` is a class called `VoiceTransmitStream` which is an inherited from `Stream` (`VoiceTransmitStream : Stream`), so I therefore have access to all the usual Stream methods/properties. `VoiceTransmitStream` is provided by another package, so I am unable to modify it. It doesn't matter how `transmitStream` is created, it is the `inStream.CopyToAsync` that matters.

How can I copy the contents of `inStream` to `transmitStream` in chunks? Pseudo code would look something like this:

```
start at offset 0 for both inStream and transmitStream
    while (true)
      read 3048 bytes from inStream
      write those 3048 bytes to the end of transmitStream
      shift the offset of inStream by 3048 bytes
      shift the offset of transmitStream by 3048 bytes
    repeat
```

`inStream` will constantly being written to as it is being filled with data from the microphone.

I basically need to want to synchronise the writing into `inStream` to `transmitStream` so I can pass the contents along to `transmitStream` for use in another API.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like below.  You can set the position before copying.  The copy starts at current position and copies to end of stream.

```
            MemoryStream mStream1 = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
            mStream1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            mStream1.Position = 0;
            MemoryStream mStream2 = new MemoryStream();
            mStream1.CopyTo(mStream2);
```